# Ajax execute successfully but didn't update database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have table with edit button on each row. Then I have ajax function which on button edit/save should save new value in database but doesn't update it.

In console I see that it is returning `Success` and the parameters are passed correctly.

This is the buttons that I have

```
foreach ($row as $r){
    echo '<tr id="row-'.$r['rate_id'].'">
             <td id="people-'.$r['number_of_people'].'">'.$r['number_of_people'].'</td>                        
             <td id="price_val-'.$r['rate_id'].'">$ '.$r['price_per_people'].'</td>
             <td>
                  <button id="edit_button'.$r['rate_id'].'" onclick="edit_row('.$r['rate_id'].')" class="btn btn-primary edit_button">Edit</button>
                  <input type="button" class="save_button" id="save_button'.$r['rate_id'].'" value="save" onclick="save_row('.$r['rate_id'].')">
             </td>
          </tr>';       
}
```

The ajax function

```
function edit_row(id)
{
 var price=document.getElementById("price_val-"+id).innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("price_val-"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='price-"+id+"' value='"+price+"'>";

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";
}

function save_row(id)
{
 var price=document.getElementById("price-"+id).value;

 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'includes/update.php',
  data:{
   edit_row:'edit_row',
   row_id:id,
   price_val:price,
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    document.getElementById("price_val-"+id).innerHTML=price;
    document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="none";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

And this is the update.php

```
require 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['edit_row']))
{


    $sql = "UPDATE new_rates SET price_per_people = :price_for_people WHERE rate_id = :rate_id";
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);                                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':price_for_people', $_POST['price_val']);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':rate_id', $_POST['row_id']);      
    $stmt->execute(); 

    echo "success";
    exit(); 
}
```

In console I see

```
edit_row:edit_row
row_id:1
price_val:$ 12
```

which seems correct except I'm not sure for the dollar sign `$` since I didn't save it in database. Must save only the price `12`.

Can someone help me to clean this a bit and make it work? Since `success` is coming on console I'm a bit lost what can be the problem.

Comment: Can you print last executed query?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson doesn't this line `document.getElementById("price_val-"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='price-"+id+"' value='"+price+"'>";` passing the price - `id='price-"+id+"'` ?

Comment: does the update happen in the database?

Comment: What data-type is your `price_per_people` column? If it's numeric, it won't accept a value like `"$ 12"`. FYI, the `$` prefix is coming from `document.getElementById("price_val-"+id).innerHTML` because your `<td>` tag has `$` in it

Comment: @AlexAndrei that's the problem - it doesn't update values in database

Comment: Yes, `price_per_people` is numeric. Is it possible to not show `$` on input field but only the numbers?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you missed where he gets `price` again in the `save_row` function

Comment: Yes, I've testes @Phil comment about the dollar `$` sign. When I delete it from input field and save only the numbers it is updating the database and it's works. Is it possible to not show the `$` in the input field?

Comment: Change this: ``<td id="price_val-'.$r['rate_id'].'">$ '.$r['price_per_people'].'</td>`` to this: ``<td>$ <span id="price_val-'.$r['rate_id'].'">'.$r['price_per_people'].'</span></td>``

Comment: @Phil - Yes I did. I'm really off my game today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating and removing the `<input>` field, I would just hide it and toggle its visibility. For example

```
foreach ($row as $r) : ?>
<tr id="row-<?= $r['rate_id'] ?>">
  <td id="people-<?= $r['number_of_people']?>"><?= $r['number_of_people'] ?></td>                        
  <td>
    $ <span id="price_val-<?= $r['rate_id'] ?>"><?= $r['price_per_people']?></span>
    <input style="display:none" type="number" min="0.00" step="0.01" value="<?= $r['price_per_people'] ?>" id="price-<?= $r['rate_id'] ?>">
  </td>
  <!-- and so on -->
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

and in your JS just toggle the visibility of your elements. The rest of your JS code should be about right.

For example

```
function edit_row(id) {
  var showThese = ['price-', 'save_button'].map(prefix => '#' + prefix + id).join(',')
  var hideThese = ['price_val', 'edit_button'].map(prefix => '#' + prefix + id).join(',')
  $(showThese).show()
  $(hideThese).hide()
}
```

and in your *success* callback

```
$('#price_val-' + id).text(price)
var hideThese = ['price-', 'save_button'].map(prefix => '#' + prefix + id).join(',')
var showThese = ['price_val', 'edit_button'].map(prefix => '#' + prefix + id).join(',')
$(showThese).show()
$(hideThese).hide()
```

---

Note I've used PHP's alternative syntax. Using `echo` to create a bunch of mostly static HTML usually leads to problems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A question about the JS part. On which function or line I should put this?

Comment: @Peter both in your `edit_row` and in the success callback. It replaces the need to create the `<input>`. I'll update my answer for clarity